# Find two vectors that are perpendicular to each other and w

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

Find two vectors $u$ and $v$ such that: $(i)$ both $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular to $w= (1,-1,-1)$ and $(ii)$ $u$ is perpendicular to $v$

So, I know how to find a vector, $u = (1,2,-1)$, that is perpendicular to $w$, but how do I find the third vector, $v$ that is perpendicular to both $u$ and $w$?

I've already tried $$v\cdot (u+w)=v\cdot u \; + v\cdot w \\ 
$$

But the result that I get does not allow for $u \cdot v = 0$ and $v \cdot w = 0$

What am I doing wrong? How should I approach solving something like this?

Please note that I'm taking Linear Algebra I, so keep the language/explanation to a level that matches my knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: How about $v = (1,0,1)$? How did you find the first vector $u$? Use a similar procedure to see what $v$ has to be? $v \cdot u = 0$ and $v \cdot w = 0$.

Comment: @Gregory If I choose two random numbers for $v_1 = 1$ and $v_2 = 3$, then I get two different answers for $v \cdot u = 0$ and $v \cdot w = 0$ . How can I find $v$ such that all of its coordinates are the same for $v \cdot u = 0$ and $v \cdot w = 0$? Or is that not possible, and $v$ has two different solutions?

Comment: The cross product of $u$ and $w$ is perpendicular to both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Here is a sketch of the solution, which you may be more interested in the future.

Take any vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\backslash\{0,w\}$ then remove its projection on the direction of $w$.

The result of such operation is going to be denoted by $u$, which is orthogonal to $w$.

Precisely, one has that
\begin{align*}
u = x - \frac{\langle x,w\rangle}{\|w\|^{2}}w
\end{align*}

Once you have $u$ and $w$, you can take the cross product $v = u\times w$, and you are done.

Hopefully this helps !